# Alternative to TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I need to very quickly draw a whole bunch of text elements with shadows in an Android app. Right now I'm using a bunch of [TextViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) for this, but looking at the documentation ("A TextView is a complete text editor...") it seems that this might be a very heavy-weight way to draw the text and on some devices (e.g. [this one](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_m580_replenish-3927.php)) the performance I get is quite terrible.

Is there a better performing alternative? I only need to be able to draw a single line of text each (no line-breaking) in a custom font with a single (potentially transparent) color and a blurred drop-shadow.

Comment: ... `canvas.drawText()`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText(java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint). Drwa twice to make a shadow (once in the shadow semitransparent color and once in the full color, shifted by an offset in x,y)

Comment: You can also have a look at [this article](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/114508858967/improving-comment-rendering-on-android) about `TextView` optimization, but it doesn't really give complete implementation.

Comment: @DerGolem I need to be able to move around the different text elements on the screen. Is there a way to have the Android compositor do that work for me if I use a canvas? Or would I have to keep redrawing the canvas myself?

Comment: You can make your own custom component which uses `canvas.drawText()`. http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: Your perf issues are more likely to be the shadows.  Especially on the device you mentioned-  it proobably doesn't have hardware acceleration for them.  WHy are you even trying to support an Android 2.x device anymore?

Comment: @GabeSechan I mentioned this specific device, because it was actually still being sold as new when I posted the question. In fact, it's was one of the cheapest Android devices on Amazon at that time. Given how difficult it is to stand out among the millions of games on the app store, I decided that, if it's doable, one might as well support every possible device, since then our game would be one of the few that shows up in the list for people owning those devices. I've meanwhile implemented my own text-drawing code using OpenGL and the performance is phenomenal on ALL devices v2.0 and up. :)

Comment: Ah.  I didn't notice the date, it got bumped for some reason.